# Create a view in any activity for use with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, objectanimator

I'd like to create a textView for use with my Android app's activity, which has a custom view inside a linearLayout.

I want to animate a TextView over my custom view - but the TextView doesn't exist in the layout because I want it to be created dynamically.  It will be an animation of a player's score with a "+500" moving upwards let's say.

The code will look something like this

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.screen_game);
TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
ll.addView(textView);
textView.setText("+500 points!");
textView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "translationY", 0,100f);
anim.setDuration(2000);
anim.start();
```

Obviously I don't really want to add the TextView to the view, because then it just gets added to the bottom of the LinearLayout at the bottom. What should I do here?

[**Update1**]
I've made good progress by adding my view to a RelativeLayout, which I then add as a child to a root FrameLayout. This works perfectly to add a view dynamically that gets created just for animation (and then disappears). But now I need more fine-grained control of where my animations will start from/go to and  AbsoluteLayout is deprecated so I'm avoiding that. Since I'm trying to place text at exact locations relative to the full-screen FrameLayout, I need to replace AbsoluteLayout with something else that can do exact X,Y locations on the screen.  I guess I've answered my question here but these points are still blockers for me at the moment.

Comment: remove or hide textview after anim ended?

Answer (score -1):

Add listener for animation.
Remove TextView when animation is end.

```
 // add listener
 anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all.  I'm asking how to create the TextView - not destroy it.